# Regex: Disable Symbols

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode, symbols

Is there any way to disable **`all`** symbols, punctuations, block elements, geometric shapes and dingbats such like these:

> ✁ ✂ ✃ ✄ ✆ ✇ ✈ ✉ ✌ ✍ ✎ ✏ ✐ ✑ ✒ ✓ ✔ ✕  ⟻ ⟼ ⟽ ⟾ ⟿  ⟻ ⟼ ⟽ ⟾ ⟿ ▚ ▛ ▜ ▝ ▞ ▟

without writing down all of them in the Regular Expression Pattern, while enable all other normal language characters such like chinese, arabic etc.. such like these:

> 文化中国 الجزيرة نت

?

I'm building a javascript validation function and my real problem is that I can't use:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]
```

Because this ignores a lots of languages too not just the symbols.

Comment: Sounds more like a character-by-character filter task than a regex task!

Comment: can you give a reason? theres probably a better way to go about this.

Comment: regex is definitely not the solution for this problem

Comment: The normal way to do this is by using Unicode properties. If you have access to those, it’s simplicity itself; if you don’t, it’s tantamount to impossible.  Last I looked javascript didn’t give you access to Unicode properties.

Comment: I've added a note below about XRegExp, which may help you, if you take advantage of the Unicode Plugin. http://xregexp.com/plugins/

Answer (score 5):

The Unicode standard divides up all the possible characters into [code charts](http://www.unicode.org/charts/). Each code chart contains related characters. If you want to exclude (or include) only certain classes of characters, you will have to make a suitable list of exclusions (or inclusions). Unicode is big, so this might be a lot of work.

Answer (score 2):

Not really.

JavaScript doesn't support [Unicode Character Properties](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html).  The closest you'll get is excluding ranges by Unicode code point as Greg Hewgill suggested.

For example, to match all of the characters under **Mathematical Symbols**:

```
/[\u2190-\u259F]/
```

Answer (score 2):

This depends on your regex dialect. Unfortunately, probably most existing JavaScript engines don't support Unicode character classes.

In regex engines such as the one in (recent) Perl or .Net, Unicode character classes can be referenced.

\p{L}: any kind of letter from any language. 
\p{N}: any number symbol from any language (including, as I recall, the Indian and Arabic and CJK number glyphs).

Because Unicode supports composed and decomposed glyphs, you may run into certain complexities: namely, if only decomposed forms exist, it's possible that you might accidentally exclude some diacritic marks in your matching pattern, and you may need to explicitly allow glyphs of the type Mark. You can mitigate this somewhat by using, if I recall correctly, a string that has been normalized using kC normalization (only for characters that have a composed form). In environments that support Unicode well, there's usually a function that allows you to normalize Unicode strings fairly easily (true in Java and .Net, at least).

**Edited to add**: If you've started down this path, or have considered it, in order to regain some sanity, you may want to experiment with the [Unicode Plugin for XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/plugins/) (which will require you to take a dependency on XRegExp).

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript regular expressions do not have native Unicode support. An alternative to to validate (or sanitize) the string at server site, or to use a non-native regex library. While I've never used it, [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/) is such a library, and it has a [Unicode Plugin](http://xregexp.com/plugins/).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Unicode Planes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29). You probably want to exclude everything but planes 0 and 2. After that, it gets ugly as you'll have to exclude a lot of plane 0 on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: Unfortunately, the characters that the poster wishes to exclude are available in the basic multilingual plane (0), so that won't get him/her very far.

Comment: @Jason: that's why I said it gets ugly; the page I linked to lists the code ranges within the BMP and also has links to a list of codepoints where necessary (eg http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C1_Controls_and_Latin-1_Supplement ), ie all the necessary information is there...